# what is in asyncio.get_event_loop(), how to register an event in the event loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio, event-loop

the code is below , my question is: 
1.what is in loop got by asyncio.get_event_loop().I thought that a loop is a place to put task in it, we need to add task in the loop first . is that correct? 
2. in the code ,
   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   get the loop at the beginning , but looks like nothing has been put into the loop yet.

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import time

def function_1(end_time, loop):
    print ("function_1 called")
    if (loop.time() + 1.0) < end_time:
        loop.call_later(1, function_2, end_time, loop)
else:
    loop.stop()

def function_2(end_time, loop):
    print ("function_2 called ")
    if (loop.time() + 1.0) < end_time:
        loop.call_later(1, function_3, end_time, loop)
    else:
    loop.stop()

def function_3(end_time, loop):
    print ("function_3 called")
    if (loop.time() + 1.0) < end_time:
        loop.call_later(1, function_1, end_time, loop)
    else:
        loop.stop()

def function_4(end_time, loop):
    print ("function_5 called")
    if (loop.time() + 1.0) < end_time:
        loop.call_later(1, function_4, end_time, loop)
    else:
        loop.stop()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
end_loop = loop.time() + 9.0
loop.call_soon(function_1, end_loop, loop)
# loop.call_soon(function_4, end_loop, loop)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

Comment: Event loops execute functions and tasks.  Your code doesn't create any tasks but it does ask the loop to execute functions 1, 2, 3.  The question of how to "register" an "event" uses some terminology you have invented yourself, so it has no answer.  What do you think an "event" is, other than a function or task?  The loop method "call_soon" requests the loop to execute the function (i.e., call it once) after the specified time has elapsed, if that's what you want to know.  There is nothing else going on in this code.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify what is actually unclear. You provide running code and ask "how" it runs, "by which code" - are you asking for an explanation of how asyncio is _implemented_, or something else?

Comment: I thought that a loop is a place to put function to be run . and we need to add function in that loop . so It looks like what I though is wrong

Comment: But what's your actual **question**? What do you want to know or are having an issue with?